# キャッシュを回避する方法以外でgifアニメを最初から再生する方法

Tags: javascript, html

https://iwb.jp/javascript-gifanimation-load/

このページにかかれているように、gifアニメーションを毎回最初から再生するには、乱数を画像の後ろにつけて毎回画像を取得する方法(キャッシュを回避する方法)があります。

しかし、何度も読み込む場合処理落ちが発生してしまいます。
これを回避する方法はキャッシュを回避する方法以外に存在するのでしょうか。

言い換えると、1度のgifアニメの取得で複数のimgタグで最初からgifアニメを再生させるにはどのようにすれば良いのでしょうか。

Comment: 何の改善にもなりませんが、この動作がBugzillaに報告されていたので参考までにリンクを貼っておきます。2002年にバグ報告されていますが、未だ`Status: NEW`です。 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=129986

Comment: JSでBlobとして取得してObjectURLを作り直すことはどうでしょうか？
カスタムエレメント化も可能だと思うのですが